# Не работает адаптив на мобилках

Tags: html, css

В dev tools выглядит всё нормально, а на мобилках почему-то не работает адаптив. Причем тот адаптив, который делал раньше, работает, а вчера добавил новый блок и сделал на нем адаптив - не работает. Сайт на Wordpress, если что. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Разобрался. В вордпресс использую плагин "Серафинит Акселератор". Он кэширует данные, и иногда бывают проблемы из-за этого. Просто вручную почистил, и всё заработало